Representing scalars as vectors for the network output
In the MuZero Paper in the Appendix F they explain that they represent values and rewards as vectors.

This means that the neural networks don't output the scalars directly,
instead, they output a probability distribution that later gets converted back to a scalar.
I wonder why it's done this way. Let's say they want to support a reward/value range of
[-60000, 60000]. They could have the network output a scalar y and then do tanh(y)*60000
or even output the actual reward or value directly.
What's the advantage of representing Scalars as Vectors?

The output becomes less deterministic

By representing the Rewards and Values as vectors, the network is able
to model uncertainty. Instead of choosing one specific reward it can give multiple possible rewards, a non-zero probability.
This stabilizes the training process, since parameter updates are based on
more information.
